# NPE set custom adapter from non activity class

Tags: android, button

iam getting NPE on my non activity class..in this activity i setup

button(setonclicklistener) to set my custom adapter..and i dont know how to fix it since iam

not good enough on programing iam so confused what must i change the code..

**here my custom AdapterListMenu class :**

```
public class AdapterListMenu extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    Context context; 

    public AdapterListMenu(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public AdapterListMenu(Context context) {
        this.context=context;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_menurow, null);

        final TextView nama_menu = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.nama_menu); // title
        TextView keterangan_menu = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.keterangan_menu); // artist name
        TextView harga_menu = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.harga_menu); // duration
        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image
        final EditText listmenu_jumlahmenu = (EditText)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtListMenu_Jumlah);       
        final Button listmenu_submit=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.btn_ListMenu_Submit);


        listmenu_submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                String nama_menus = nama_menu.getText().toString();
                String jumlah_menus = listmenu_jumlahmenu.getText().toString();
                MenuInputClass sr = new MenuInputClass();
                sr.setNama_menu(nama_menus);
                sr.setJumlah_menu(jumlah_menus);
                Appetizer_Activity.results.add(sr); 
                ListPemesanan_Activity.list_pemesanan.setAdapter(new AdapterListPemesananMenu(getApplicationContext(), Appetizer_Activity.results));
             --->i think the  problem is here


            }

            private Context getApplicationContext() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            });

        HashMap<String, String> listmenudisplay = new HashMap<String, String>();
        listmenudisplay = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        nama_menu.setText(listmenudisplay.get(ListAppetizer_Activity.parser_nama_menu));
        keterangan_menu.setText(listmenudisplay.get(ListAppetizer_Activity.parser_keterangan_menu));
        harga_menu.setText(listmenudisplay.get(ListAppetizer_Activity.parser_harga_menu));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(listmenudisplay.get(ListAppetizer_Activity.parser_gambar), thumb_image);
        return vi;
    }
```

**adapter list pemesanan menu class :**

```
public class AdapterListPemesananMenu extends BaseAdapter {
    public static ArrayList<MenuInputClass> searchArrayList;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public AdapterListPemesananMenu(Context context, ArrayList<MenuInputClass> results) {
        searchArrayList = results;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }



    public AdapterListPemesananMenu(OnClickListener onClickListener,
            ArrayList<MenuInputClass> searchResults) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



    public int getCount() {
        return searchArrayList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return searchArrayList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_pemesananmenu_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtNamaMasuk);
            holder.txtCityState = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtJumlahMasuk);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtName.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getNama_menu());
        holder.txtCityState.setText(searchArrayList.get(position)
                .getJumlah_menu());


        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtCityState;

    }
}
```

**list pemesanan menu xml layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.76" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:text="No Meja :" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtNoMeja"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtNoMeja"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
            android:textColor="#ffff00"
            >

        </ListView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_submit_list_pemesanan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Submit" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**list pemesanan menu row layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNamaMasuk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/textbody" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtJumlahMasuk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/textbody" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtJumlahMasuk"
        android:text="Jumlah :"
        android:textColor="@color/textbody" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**this is logcat :**

```
10-31 03:44:23.111: E/AndroidRuntime(13386): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 03:44:23.111: E/AndroidRuntime(13386): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-31 03:44:23.111: E/AndroidRuntime(13386):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:171)
10-31 03:44:23.111: E/AndroidRuntime(13386):    at xml_parser_and_adapter.AdapterListPemesananMenu.<init>(AdapterListPemesananMenu.java:25)
10-31 03:44:23.111: E/AndroidRuntime(13386):    at xml_parser_and_adapter.AdapterListMenu$4.onClick(AdapterListMenu.java:158)
10-31 03:44:23.111: E/AndroidRuntime(13386):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
10-31 03:44:23.111: E/AndroidRuntime(13386):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
10-31 03:44:23.111: E/AndroidRuntime(13386):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-31 03:44:23.111: E/AndroidRuntime(13386):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-31 03:44:23.111: E/AndroidRuntime(13386):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-31 03:44:23.111: E/AndroidRuntime(13386):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3693)
10-31 03:44:23.111: E/AndroidRuntime(13386):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 03:44:23.111: E/AndroidRuntime(13386):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-31 03:44:23.111: E/AndroidRuntime(13386):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
10-31 03:44:23.111: E/AndroidRuntime(13386):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
```

what must i do?

thank you...

replace my code with :

```
ListPemesanan_Activity.list_pemesanan.setAdapter(new AdapterListPemesananMenu(activity, Appetizer_Activity.results));


11-01 16:56:26.108: E/AndroidRuntime(7758): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 16:56:26.108: E/AndroidRuntime(7758): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-01 16:56:26.108: E/AndroidRuntime(7758):     at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:228)
11-01 16:56:26.108: E/AndroidRuntime(7758):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1888)
11-01 16:56:26.108: E/AndroidRuntime(7758):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1931)
11-01 16:56:26.108: E/AndroidRuntime(7758):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:292)
11-01 16:56:26.108: E/AndroidRuntime(7758):     at android.widget.AdapterView.<init>(AdapterView.java:228)
11-01 16:56:26.108: E/AndroidRuntime(7758):     at android.widget.AbsListView.<init>(AbsListView.java:686)
11-01 16:56:26.108: E/AndroidRuntime(7758):     at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:188)
11-01 16:56:26.108: E/AndroidRuntime(7758):     at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:184)
11-01 16:56:26.108: E/AndroidRuntime(7758):     at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:180)
11-01 16:56:26.108: E/AndroidRuntime(7758):     at xml_parser_and_adapter.AdapterListMenu$4.onClick(AdapterListMenu.java:152)
11-01 16:56:26.108: E/AndroidRuntime(7758):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
11-01 16:56:26.108: E/AndroidRuntime(7758):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
11-01 16:56:26.108: E/AndroidRuntime(7758):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-01 16:56:26.108: E/AndroidRuntime(7758):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-01 16:56:26.108: E/AndroidRuntime(7758):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-01 16:56:26.108: E/AndroidRuntime(7758):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3693)
11-01 16:56:26.108: E/AndroidRuntime(7758):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-01 16:56:26.108: E/AndroidRuntime(7758):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
```

Comment: Please add the code for `AdapterListPemesananMenu` and the layout's XML.

Comment: try passing activity context to AdapterListPemesananMenu

Comment: @wasaig can you give me snippet code?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ListPemesanan_Activity.list_pemesanan.setAdapter(new AdapterListPemesananMenu(activity, Appetizer_Activity.results));
         --->i think the  problem is here
```

instead of

```
ListPemesanan_Activity.list_pemesanan.setAdapter(new AdapterListPemesananMenu(getApplicationContext(), Appetizer_Activity.results));
         --->i think the  problem is here
```